# How do I move (rearrange) the orientation of a video? Using ffmpeg

Tags: video-editor, ffmpeg

I want to crop the video at some position and move the part next to the part that wasn't cropped. (See image, it explains better)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v] crop=iw/3:ih:0:0,pad=iw:2*ih [left]; \
 [0:v] crop=iw/3:ih:(iw/3)+1:0 [middle]; \
 [0:v] crop=iw/3:ih:(2*iw/3)+1:0 [right]; \
 [left][middle] overlay=0:main_h/2,pad=iw:(3*ih/2) [out1]; \
 [out1][right] overlay=0:(2*main_h/3) [fout] " \
  -c:v libx264 -an -map "[fout]" trisected-vertical-overlay.mp4
```

I haven't supplied any specific video or audio encoding parameters. This just shows the overlay filter to use. You'll have to encode and map the audio, as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Using [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) and [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack):

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=iw/3:ih:0:0[left]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/3[center]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/3:ih:ow*2:0[right]; \
 [left][center][right]vstack=inputs=3[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output
```

- vstack is faster than pad + overlay.
- If your `ffmpeg` is too old for the vstack filter then just [download a recent build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).